# Convert String binary to integer Java

Tags: java, algorithm

While reading this [book](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/61data/) I came across converting binary to integer. 
The code that is given by the book is:

```
 // convert a String of 0's and 1's into an integer
    public static int fromBinaryString(String s) {
       int result = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
          char c = s.charAt(i);
          if      (c == '0') result = 2 * result;
          else if (c == '1') result = 2 * result + 1;
       }
       return result;
    }
```

and the way I solved the problem is:

```
public static int fromBinary(String s) {
        int result = 0;
        int powerOfTwo = 0;
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if ('1' == s.charAt(i)) {
                result += Math.pow(2, powerOfTwo);
            }
            powerOfTwo++;
        }
 return result;
    }
```

I know my code has an extra counter and it is probably a bit slowly but the way I implement the solution is by following the polynomial definition

x = xn b^n + xn-1 b^n-1 + ... + x1 b^1 + x0 b^0.

What I don't understand is how their's solution works ?
I've already debugged but still can't find what is key. Can someone explain ?

Comment: Anything wrong with `Integer.parseInt(s, 2)`? They simply set each "bit" of the `int` manually, so either `1` or `0` and bitshift.

Comment: Sidenote: the code above misses the `else` case which probably should be used to detect non-binary strings, i.e. characters that aren't 0 or 1.

Comment: @BoristheSpider it's probably more for teaching the conversion and binary itself. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying your polynomial definition **x = xn b^n + xn-1 b^n-1 + ... + x1 b^1 + x0 b^0** you can rewrite this to

```
x = ((((...(((( xn * b + xn-1 ) * b + ...  )* b + x1 ) * b + x0
```

where you have b=2 for binary representation and you have n-1 parenthesis opening on the left most side.

For n=4 this reads like

```
x = ((((x3*2)+x2)*2+x1)*2+x0 = x3 * 2^3 + x2 * 2^2 + x1 * 2^1 + x0 * 2^0
```

If you are parsing the string begining with the MSB (`x_n`) towards LSB (`x_0`), when reading `x_i` you will have to execute

```
 result = result * 2 + x_i
```

Before executing this `result` would have stored the value

```
((...(((( xn * b + xn-1 ) * b + ...  )* b + x_(i+1) )
```

After executing this `result` would have stored the value

```
((...(((( xn * b + xn-1 ) * b + ...  )* b + x_i )
```

Reasoning by induction you can prove you compute the correct answer in the end.

Answer (score 5):

They basically shift the result with `2 * result` and add 1 if the bit is set.

Example: 01101

```
1. iteration: result = 0 -> result * 2 = 0      (same as binary 00000)
2. iteration: result = 0 -> result * 2 + 1 = 1  (same as binary 00001)
3. iteration: result = 1 -> result * 2 + 1 = 3  (same as binary 00011)  
4. iteration: result = 3 -> result * 2 = 6      (same as binary 00110)
5. iteration: result = 6 -> result * 2 + 1 = 13 (same as binary 01101)
```

In terms of bits: 8 + 4 + 1 = 13

Alternatively you could replace `result = result * 2` with `result <<= 1` but adding 1 in a single statement would not work then. You could write `result = (result << 1) + 1` but that's longer and harder to read than the multiplication.

Comment: I suppose one could first `<<=` in either case then add `1` if `c == 1`. That would save you the else, and would make it clear that the shifting always happens.